# What method to use in rest webservice

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-architecture

I am developing an restful webservice for an app as follows:

I have a bunch of images that needs to be processed by the rest client, but when I ask for these images they are signed in the database by the server, so it is not retrieved twice by the clients.
I have a question, since GET must be idempotent what method is the best for this operation? Should I consider GET anyway, since if the same client requests the images it receives the same images?

I was thinking of something like:

/images/assign

But I am not sure what is the best method to use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think that 'get' is fine. It is up to you if some method is either save or idempotent. So you can implement get in order to what you want to get.

You do no modify your resource by sending it to the client, so you can use get method.

Is it helpfull?